# T-SQL LIKE condition on comma-separated list

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-ce

Is it possible to write a `LIKE` condition in T-SQL to match a comma-separated list which includes wildcards to a string. Let me explain further with an example:

Say you have the following command separated list of urls in a field:

```
'/, /news/%, /about/'
```

Now here's some examples of strings I'd like to match with the string above:

1. '/'
2. '/news/'
3. '/news/2/'
4. '/about/'

And here's some strings which would not match:

1. '/contact/'
2. '/about/me/'

I've achieved this in the past by writing a split function and then doing a like on each one. However I'm trying to get my query to work in SQL Server CE which doesn't support functions.

In case you are wondering here's how I achieved it using the split function:

```
SELECT Widgets.Id 
FROM Widgets 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Split](Urls, ',') WHERE @Input LIKE Data) > 0
```

And here's the split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(    
    @RowData NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Separator NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE 
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Data] NVARCHAR(MAX)
) 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Iterator INT
    SET @Iterator = 1

    DECLARE @FoundIndex INT
    SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @RowData)

    WHILE (@FoundIndex > 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue ([Data])
        SELECT Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@RowData, 1, @FoundIndex - 1)))

        SET @RowData = SUBSTRING(@RowData, @FoundIndex + DATALENGTH(@Separator) / 2, LEN(@RowData))
        SET @Iterator = @Iterator + 1
        SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @RowData)
    END

    INSERT INTO @RtnValue ([Data])
    SELECT Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@RowData))

    RETURN
END
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could help. Thanks

Comment: The answer to your question is "no".  You might investigate regular expressions.  Alternatively, if you keep your "comma separated list" as a separate table with one item per row, then you could use like with a join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of several options:

1. Use a session-keyed table: delete rows matching current spid, insert desired rows with current spid, read from table in SP, delete from table (again).
2. Make your client submit a query with many OR ... LIKE ... clauses.
3. Write an SP that does the same thing as your function and returns a recordset. `INSERT YourTable EXEC SP @Strings` and you are done!
4. Use the numbers-table-charindex-into-string inside of a derived table method of splitting the string.

**Example**

Let me flesh this out a little for you with an example combining ideas #3 and #4. Of course, your code for your function could be adapted, too.

Build a separate `Numbers` table. Here is example creation script:

```
--Numbers Table with 8192 elements (keeping it small for CE)
CREATE TABLE Numbers (
   N smallint NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);
INSERT Numbers VALUES (1);
WHILE @@RowCount < 4096
   INSERT Numbers SELECT N + (SELECT Max(N) FROM Numbers) FROM Numbers;
```

The SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StringSplitRowset
   @String varchar(8000)
AS
SELECT Substring(@String, l.StartPos, l.Chars) Item
FROM (
   SELECT
      S.StartPos,
      IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(',', @String, S.StartPos), 0) - S.StartPos, 8000)
   FROM (
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT N.N + 1 FROM Numbers N WHERE Substring(@String, N.N, 1) = ','
   ) S (StartPos)
) L (StartPos, Chars);
```

And usage, easy as pie:

```
DECLARE @String varchar(8000);
SET @String = 'abc,def,ghi,jkl';
CREATE TABLE #Split (S varchar(8000));
INSERT #Split EXEC dbo.StringSplitRowset @String;
SELECT * FROM #Split;
```

Result:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

And finally, if you don't want to build a numbers table, you can use this SP. I think you will find that one of these two SPs performs well enough for you. There are other implementations of string splitting that could work as well.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StringSplitRowset
  @String varchar(8000)
AS
SELECT Substring(@String, l.StartPos, l.Chars) Item
FROM (
   SELECT
      S.StartPos,
      IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(',', @String, S.StartPos), 0) - S.StartPos, 8000)
   FROM (
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT N.N + 1
      FROM (
         SELECT A.A * 4096 + B.B * 1024 + C.C * 256 + D.D * 64 + E.E * 16 + F.F * 4 + G.G N
         FROM
            (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) A (A),
            (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) G (G),
            (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) F (F),
            (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) E (E),
            (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) D (D),
            (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) C (C),
            (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) B (B)
      ) N (N)
      WHERE Substring(@String, N.N, 1) = ','
   ) S (StartPos)
) L (StartPos, Chars)
```

Any SQL writer serious about understanding some of the performance implications of splitting strings different ways ought to see [Aaron Bertrand's blog post on splitting strings](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

Also, any serious SQL Server database student ought to see [Erland Sommarskog's How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html).

Answer (score 0):

Will SQL Server CE let you split with XML functions and use CROSS APPLY?  If so, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.id
FROM (
      SELECT id,  CAST(('<X>'+
                        REPLACE(REPLACE(urls,' ',''),',','</X><X>')+
                        '</X>'
                       ) AS xml
                      ) as URLsXML
      FROM dbo.Widgets
     ) AS T1
CROSS APPLY(
            SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(50)') AS URLPattern 
            FROM URLsXML.nodes('X') AS S(N)
           ) AS T2
WHERE @Input LIKE T2.URLPattern
```

**UPDATE**:  I just checked.  It looks like SQL Server CE doesn't support the XML data type or CROSS APPLY.
I think you will have to populate another table with ID's and Patterns to join against.